# Local variables won't change inside OnCompleteListener

Tags: android, kotlin

What I'm trying to do here is to get all the needed information from the database and use it to create a new Account instance. However, for some reason after the addOnCompleteListener part ends the values name, username,...etc won't change. Why is that?

```
private fun initlAccount(uid:String):Account{
    var name = ""
    var username = ""
    var dob = ""
    var email = ""
    val friends = ArrayList<Account>()
    var tasks = ArrayList<Task>()
    db.collection("users").document(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener {
        if(it.isSuccessful){
            name = it.result.getString("Full name")!!
            username = it.result.getString("Username")!!
            dob = it.result.getString("Date of Birth")!!
            email = it.result.getString("Email")!!
            var arrtemp = it.result.get("Friends") as ArrayList<String>
            for(str in arrtemp){
                friends.add(initlAccount(str))
            }
            arrtemp = it.result.get("Tasks") as ArrayList<String>
            tasks = getTasks(arrtemp)
        }
    }
    val acc = Account(uid,username,name,dob,email,tasks,friends)
    println(acc.toString())
    return acc
}
```

Comment: You cannot return from this method. It is asynchronous

Comment: In other words, the values *are changing*, just not when you are *expecting them to*

Comment: Then how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
val acc = Account(uid,username,name,dob,email,tasks,friends)
println(acc.toString())
return acc
```

this code gets executed before the code inside on onCompleteListener. You should create the `Account` inside the completion listener. Ofcourse you can't return from inside the listener, so make the `val acc` as a member variable instead of local. I don't know your complete code, so can't give much suggestion regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

The values *are changing*, just not when you are expecting them to

Change the method signature to pass in the completion listener and return nothing

```
private fun initlAccount(uid:String, listener:OnCompleteListener) {

   ...

   db.collection("users").document(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener(listener)
}  // End of method
```

Move the listener body to the place you call this method, which makes it "callback" into the other thread and therefore "returning the execution results"

Note: I don't know Kotlin, but something like this

```
initlAccount("uid-value", OnCompleteListener { it ->
    if(it.isSuccessful){
        val result = it.result

        name = result.getString("Full name")!!
        username = result.getString("Username")!!
        dob = result.getString("Date of Birth")!!
        email = result.getString("Email")!!
        var arrtemp = result.get("Friends") as ArrayList<String>
        for(str in arrtemp){
            friends.add(initlAccount(str)) // Note: This is recursive, and will be an issue
        }
        arrtemp = result.get("Tasks") as ArrayList<String>
        tasks = getTasks(arrtemp)
        val acc = Account(uid,username,name,dob,email,tasks,friends)
        println(acc.toString())

        // Your account is returned here, so you can update a UI element, for example
    }
}) // end initlAccount method call

// do NOT use acc here, it will be unassigned or null
```

And I see you are doing a recursive call, so you should either make the database query handle that itself so the client is not in an endless cycle (a "friendship" should be reflexive - userA is a friend of userB, so getting the account of userB would return back to getting the friends of userA, and continue on) or you can try researching RxJava / Kotlin `flatMap` operators.

Comment: I tried your solution but no use. The code inside the listener still executes after the println statement

Comment: You cannot use `acc` outside of the `OnCompleteListener` method block. My answer doesn't include any code after the print, so I don't think it's my answer that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a method that returns an `Account`.

> Why not query directly to retrieve the `Account`? because doing it results in an unsynchronized workflow.

```
   db.collection("users").document(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener {
        if(it.isSuccessful){
            name = it.result.getString("Full name")!!
            username = it.result.getString("Username")!!
            dob = it.result.getString("Date of Birth")!!
            email = it.result.getString("Email")!!
            var arrtemp = it.result.get("Friends") as ArrayList<String>
            for(str in arrtemp){
                friends.add(initlAccount(str))
            }
            arrtemp = it.result.get("Tasks") as ArrayList<String>
            tasks = getTasks(arrtemp)

            val acc = Account(uid,username,name,dob,email,tasks,friends)
            println(acc.toString())
            // Probably do a save in Database?
        }
    }
```